# Migration from Google Drive to Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-drive-api, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have an android app to build and view the portfolio details. I also have the facility to import and export the portfolio details. The import and export uses the google drive to save and retrieve the data. Now Google want us to move to Cloud Firestore.

**Question**

1. I understand that the data we store for an user from his device in cloudstore which is getting shared across the users. is it correct ? I do not want the portfolio of a person to be visible to other.
2. Does the cloudstore support the individual user database ?
3. What is the better way to migrate from google drive to firebase product ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions,

1. Use Firebase Auth with CloudStore

If you're looking to save user data on CloudStore, it makes sense to use Firebase Auth as well. That way as soon as any user logs in, you can save their data against their user id only ($uid). You will have to setup security rules accordingly so only logged in user can access their data.

For example, in firestore your collection will be something similar to this

```
users/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/data
```

and its corresponding security rule should be

```
match /users/{userId}/data {
  allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

More on this here - [Secure user Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security).

2. Yes, it does. But you'll need to work with Firebase Auth too to implement this.

...if by "individual user database" you mean to store data specific to particular user only, and not allow anybody else to access that data. There are various tutorials online for this.

3. I haven't migrated from Drive to CloudStore (and I couldn't find any guides for this online as well) so I'm not the best person to answer this. But AFAIK, you might have to setup CloudStore and Auth from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can check the documentation about [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam). Permissions are granted by setting policies that grant roles to a user, group, or service account. In addition to the primitive roles, **owner, editor, and viewer**, you can grant Cloud Datastore roles to the users of your project. Yes, the cloudstore support the individual user database. You can check the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview). Instead of migrating, you can try to [integrate the Google Drive to Firebase/Firestore](https://zapier.com/apps/firebase/integrations/google-drive/).

Comment: I am talking about Cloud Firestore from firebase and not about cloud Datastore from Google cloud. The link you have given is about cloud Datastore from Google cloudhttps://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview